# How to remove xTextLabel in a barChart?

Tags: codenameone

The code to draw a bar chart as follows:

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
renderer.setXLabels(4);
renderer.setYLabels(4);
ChartLabel chartLabel = getChartLabelfromString(dateL);
for (int i=0; i<chartLabel.labelIdxs.size(); i++){
    renderer.addXTextLabel(chartLabel.labelIdxs.get(i),chartLabel.labelStrs.get(i));
}
BarChart chart = new BarChart(buildBarDataset(titles, valueDDL), renderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
```

chartLabel.labelIdxs.size() = 4

There are two strange values in the xlabels marked as red color. How do I remove the values 5,10 in the Xaxis?

[image]

Barchart Sample Code Output with labels A B C D
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's trying to draw an additional label for may and October but that doesn't make much sense since the place where it's marked is weird. I suggest playing a bit with the renderer and the data. If you can't get it to work I'll need a way to reproduce this.

Comment: In the future I suggest using github for such sources.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to remove a symbol from your Watchlist.

Using the Links Column

1. Click on the Links icon.
2. Select "Delete from Watchlist". The symbol is immediately removed.

Comment: Is this a gpt answer? It seems to be unrelated to the question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're setting the font size to be relatively large with long labels so they override each other. You can set the angle of the text to fit longer text or you can shrink the font size but there's a limit to what can physically fit under a chart. I suggest just using the month denominator in the labels.

There might be other options since the renderer class includes a lot of them.

Comment: I uploaded the main source to Github.
https://github.com/danieltsai1230/barchar-label-example

Comment: The javadoc says it's approximate. It isn't guaranteed. It also seems that this specific attribute is [ignored by default](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/da750f222a7ad21e415bc05c3f6afc06df905228/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/charts/views/XYChart.java#L371).

Comment: This issue is only for the bar chart but not for the area chart and the line chart.